# Use Jdbc to connect Persistent:Can not perform the operation because the cluster is inactive

Tags: ignite

I start ignite 2.1 by Ignite.sh and Config is

```
    <property name="persistentStoreConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.PersistentStoreConfiguration">
            <property name="persistentStorePath" value="/tools/ignite/ignite-save/presisent/"></property>
            <property name="walStorePath" value="/tools/ignite/ignite-save/wal/"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and I use jdbc to connect it,there is an error，activeOnStart is useless,How can I active the node??If I use main class to start ignite and set ignite active ,It is ok,How can I active ignite node by ignite.sh??

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Failed to query Ignite.
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinStatement.execute0(JdbcThinStatement.java:123)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcThinStatement.java:129)
        at org.apache.ignite.examples.datagrid.JdbcExample.main(JdbcExample.java:50)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
    Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Error server response: [req=JdbcQueryExecuteRequest [schemaName=null, pageSize=1024, maxRows=0, sqlQry=CREATE TABLE city (id LONG PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR) WITH "template=replicated", args=null], resp=JdbcResponse [res=null, status=1, err=class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException: Unexpected DLL operation failure: Can not perform the operation because the cluster is inactive. Note, that the cluster is considered inactive by default if Ignite Persistent Store is used to let all the nodes join the cluster. To activate the cluster call Ignite.activate(true).]]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinTcpIo.sendRequest(JdbcThinTcpIo.java:253)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinTcpIo.queryExecute(JdbcThinTcpIo.java:227)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinStatement.execute0(JdbcThinStatement.java:109)
        ... 7 more
```

Comment: Why do you think that activeOnStart is useless?

Comment: I add activeOnStart to the configuration,it does not work

Comment: Can you share your logs and code snippet when you activate cluster?

Answer (score 1):

You can use $IGNITE_HOME/bin/control.sh script to activate/deactivate the cluster.